# iphone Distribution App in app store. real name

Tags: iphone

I am ready for distribute for my first iphone app in app store. I am an individual developer.I want to confirm from any experience individual developer who already distribute app in app store.

The question is i donot want to myself real name appear in my app. can i have another display name w instead of my real name appear with my app.

Comment: iphone -> iPhone, Distribution -> distribution, App -> app, app store -> App Store, real -> Real. Please watch your capital letters so it's easier for people to read it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Will improve next time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Careful**

You can enter anything you want for the company name that appears i the app store but beware **you can not change it once entered**.  This is knows as "Artist/Show" in Apple's reports.  In order to have it changed you will have to contact Apple and it may take some time to get it corrected.  In my case it took several months and several requests.

Read the docs carefully before entering anything, is clearly stated that the company name that appears in the app store can not be changed.

Comment: wow.thanks a lot. i will be careful to think the name

Answer (score 3):

When you submit your app, even under an individual developer account, it will ask you for a company name.  You can provide your own name or a company name you'd like to have appear in the listings.  The company name you provide here will be used on your app's details page, but it will NOT be used everywhere across the board.  The name you used to create your individual developer account will always show up in some places, such as "Other apps by this developer".

Comment: Thanks a lot, you answer my questions too.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you'll have to consult with Apple to list your App under a different one than your developer license and provisioning. I made the leap to become an LLC even though I am the only one at the company I own doing iPhone dev so far, before I applied for the license to do the programming.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do what you're asking - get in touch with Apple. Or reapply under a different name (perhaps a company, as suggested by @Devin Ceartas) and pay the fee again, then just publish the app under that account.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the name on your account to the one you want shown, you need to contact apple for this